# "cannot read property 'push' of undefined" in recursive function, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Problem function:

```
  filterItemsMonth(items, start, end, arr){
    console.log(arr);

     if(!start.isAfter(end, "day")) {
       console.log(arr);
       arr.push(this.filterItemsWeek(items, start, start.add(1, "week")), [])
       start.add(1, "week");
       this.filterItemsMonth(items, start, end, arr);
     }
     return arr;
   }
```

Which is calling this function:

```
  filterItemsWeek(items, start, end, arr){
    arr.push((items.filter((item) => {
      return start.isSame(moment(item.date_started), "day");
      })).sort((a, b) => {
        return parseInt(a.time_started) - parseInt(b.time_started);
      }));
    if(!start.isSame(end, "day")) {
      start.add(1, "day");
      this.filterItemsWeek(items, start, end, arr);
    }
      return arr;
  }
```

I'm sorry for the formatting, hopefully that code is legible enough.

The below function, filterItemsWeek works properly. It takes an array of objects and sorts them based on their date property, taking only the objects from a given week and putting then in a subarray corresponding to a day of the week.

I wanted to replicate the same functionality but for an entire month, which I thought would work but I am having trouble with. Ideally, I run the bottom recursive function once for each week in a month, so I'd have an array of weeks, each array containing an array of events happening on that day in the week.

For some reason, I am getting a console error "cannot read property .push of undefined". The console.log statements show the correct value (an empty array [], which the function is passed) but for some reason my function thinks that empty array is undefined.

I am using React JS, but I do not think this is a React issue. The filterItemsWeek function works just fine, and both functions are bound to my components constructor. Any help is appreciated, this one is a real doozy for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr.push(this.filterItemsWeek(items, start, start.add(1, "week")), [])
```

should be:

```
arr.push(this.filterItemsWeek(items, start, start.add(1, "week"), []))
```

Comment: The statement you've proposed is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it.

Comment: Holy cow can't believe I missed that!